# stringr::str_starts returns TRUE when it shouldn't

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to detect whether a string starts with either of the provided strings (separated by | )

```
name = "KKSWAP"
stringr::str_starts(name, "RTT|SWAP")
```

returns TRUE, but

```
str_starts(name, "SWAP|RTT")
```

returns FALSE

This behaviour seems wrong, as KKSWAP doesn't start with "RTT" or "SWAP". I would expect this to be false in both above cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason can be found in the code of the function :

```
function (string, pattern, negate = FALSE) 
{
    switch(type(pattern), empty = , bound = stop("boundary() patterns are not supported."), 
        fixed = stri_startswith_fixed(string, pattern, negate = negate, 
            opts_fixed = opts(pattern)), coll = stri_startswith_coll(string, 
            pattern, negate = negate, opts_collator = opts(pattern)), 
        regex = {
            pattern2 <- paste0("^", pattern)
            attributes(pattern2) <- attributes(pattern)
            str_detect(string, pattern2, negate)
        })
}
```

You can see, it pastes '^' in front of the parttern, so in your example it looks for '^RR|SWAP' and finds 'SWAP'.

If you want to look at more than one pattern you should use a vector:

```
name <- "KKSWAP"
stringr::str_starts(name, c("RTT","SWAP"))
# [1] FALSE FALSE
```

If you want just one answer, you can combine with `any()`

```
name <- "KKSWAP"
stringr::str_starts(name, c("RTT","SWAP"))
# [1] FALSE
```

The advantage of `stringr::str_starts()` is the vectorisation of the pattern argument, but if you don't need it `grepl('^RTT|^SWAP', name)`, as suggested by TTS, is a good base R alternative.

Alternatively, the base function `startsWith()` suggested by jpsmith offers both the vectorized and | options :

```
startsWith(name, c("RTT","SWAP"))
# [1] FALSE FALSE

startsWith(name, "RTT|SWAP")
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: @carlganz submitted a patch for this bug https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/commit/f70c4bad938815e66c930ff6ecde15d166e04bb5

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the stringr version, but the base R version `startsWith` returns your desired result. If you don't have to use stringr, this may be a solution:

```
startsWith(name, "RTT|SWAP")
startsWith(name, "SWAP|RTT")
startsWith(name, "KK")

# > startsWith(name, "RTT|SWAP")
# [1] FALSE
# > startsWith(name, "SWAP|RTT")
# [1] FALSE
# > startsWith(name, "KK")
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

The help text describes `str_starts`: **Detect the presence or absence of a pattern at the beginning or end of a string.** This might be why it's not behaving quite as expected.

`pattern` is the **Pattern with which the string starts or ends**.

We can add `^` regex to make it search at the beginning of string and get the expected result.

```
name = 'KKSWAP'
str_starts(name, '^RTT|^SWAP')
```

I would prefer `grepl` in this instance because it seems less misleading.

```
grepl('^RTT|^SWAP', name)
```

Comment: I believe the statement "*Detect the presence or absence of a pattern at the beginning or end of a string*" applies to `str_starts` (*beginning of a string*) and `str_ends` (*end of a string*), where they shared the same page of documentation. See `?str_starts` and `?str_ends`.